# Can full nodes confirm bitcoin transactions, or only verify?

Tags: bitcoin

I have searched and searched and can't find the answer.  If you are running a full node, can you **confirm** transactions.  Or do you just verify/relay transactions?  Or is it only miners that can confirm transactions?  When I say confirm, I mean, when you spend some bitcoin, you need X confirmations (usually 6) for it to go through.  Who does the confirmations?  Can it be full nodes? Or is it only miners?

What I mean is, in the wallet, you see X confirmations.  **Who** makes that number go up?  (Say, for example, from 0 to 1).  Is it miners, full nodes, or both.  Realizing that miners run full nodes.  But I mean, full nodes that are not miners.  Can they add a confirmation?  Or does it have to be a miner?

Comment: "you need X confirmations (usually 6) for it to go through" --- what does "to go through" means? One may need 0 confirmations, just a signed transaction, depending on their purposes. For a transaction to be added in the ledger it should be included in the block. To be included in the block - the block should be mined.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You may be able to get help on our sister site [bitcoin.se].

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are confirmed by blocks being added to the blockchain. A transaction's first confirmation is when it is included in a block and that block is mined (added to the blockchain). Each subsequent block added to the blockchain on top of that transaction's block means another confirmation. So a transaction has a number of confirmations equal to its depth in the blockchain.

Confirmations happen because of blocks being added to the blockchain through the process of mining, so per your question, **only miners can confirm transactions**. Once a block is added, full nodes verify and relay that block, but only miners do the work of actually confirming the transaction.